# Show that $G$ satisfies Hall's condition

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

> Show that $G$ satisfies Hall's condition
> [image: graph]

I knew the definition:

> Let $G$ be a bipartite graph with partite sets $U$ and $W$, where $r=|U|\leq|W|$. Then $G$ satisfies Hall's condition if, for every $S\subseteq U$, $|S|\leq|N(S)|$.

But did I need to check it for all subsets manually to answer that question? Because I easily found a perfect match. And Hall condition implies the existence of a perfect match, but I don't know the reverse is true or not? Then how to deal with this question without huge amount of checking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And Hall's condition implies the existence of a perfect match, but I don't know the reverse is true or not?

Suppose that you found a perfect match but that Hall's condition were not satisfied. Then there would exist some $S \subseteq U$ for which $|S| > |N(S)|$. It would be impossible to match all the elements of $S$, a contradiction.

In other words, if you found a perfect match, then you are done.

Comment: I see. More neighborhood have settle the perfect match, isn't? @Théophile

Comment: @WhyGraph_ There are two directions. The easy direction is that Hall's condition is *necessary* (because otherwise some set $S$ does not have enough neighbours). The harder direction, and the more surprising one, is that Hall's condition is *sufficient* (i.e., we don't need to impose any further restrictions). To look at your problem another way, let $M(S)$ be the set of elements matched to $S$ in your matching. Clearly $M(S) \subseteq N(S)$, so we have $|S| = |M(S)| \leq |N(S)|$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one direction of Hall's Theorem is easy to see: If a *bipartite* graph $G$ has a perfect matching, then $G$ satisfies Hall's Condition. [The other direction: If $G$ satisfies Hall's Condition, then $G$ has a perfect matching, is the harder direction to see.] However here $G$ does have a perfect matching $M$; in fact $M$ is as follows: $M=\{1a, 2c,3b,4d,5f,6e\}$.

Comment: That's mean we could transform the original graph problem to a lower vertices graph problem. But I was wondering is there any logic to pick appropriate sub graph? or this concept help us to show a graph is not satisfy hall condition as we create counterexample to produce an appropriate subgraph? @Mike

Comment: "...if any subgraph $M$ of $G$" — this doesn't sound right. For example, take any subgraph with no vertices from $S$; then Hall's Condition is trivially satisfied.

Comment: You are correct @Théophile, I should have said *spanning subgraph*. But it is easy to see one direction of Hall's Theorem: If A bipartite graph $G$ has a perfect matching, then $G$ satisfies Hall's Condition. And that is what $M$ in my answer is. I editted for clarity.

Comment: Got it; that makes a lot more sense!